# Difference between Coordinating conjunction and correlative conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, correlating-conjunctions

What is the difference between coordinating conjunction and correlative conjunction?

Because they both used to connect two parts of a sentence with equal value

Comment: Welcome to the ELL Stack Exchange! Just so you know, we expect users to search for answers and do some research on their own before asking questions here. A google search would give you a lot of hits. If you've done this already, please tell us what you learned, and what aspects you're still confused about. For more info on how to write good questions, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Correlative conjunctions occur in pairs, for example, *either/or*, *both/and*.
Coordinating conjunctions appear singly, for example, *and*, *or*, *but*.

Here is a short article about the differences:
[TalkEnglish.com coordinating and correlative conjunctions](https://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/conjunctions-coordinating-correlative.aspx)